# Как запустить yarn run в windows?

Tags: npm, yarn

При запуске 
yarn run local

в windows выскакивает ошибка из-за переменных окружения

> "MONGO_URL" не является внутренней или внешней..

А как правильно запускать приложение в windows? 
Есть ли в yarn аналог npm cross-env?

Comment: если так пишет, то что мешает сделать ее такой? вбейте в `path`

Comment: [yarn get started](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable) не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решается с помощью cross-env.
Его можно установить через пакетный менеджер.

А дальше использовать перед переменными окружения.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```